# Query that generates random unique numbers within a specific range for columns within the same row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make it so any given row inserted into my table will have a random assortment of numbers within a specific range, let's say 1-5 for 5 columns that take in numbers...but if a number has already been inserted into a column, only the remaining numbers can be used for the rest.

What do I need to do to accomplish this? Here's an example of what I've done so far to populate 10 rows. (name column is fine as is, but thought I'd include it just in case that factors into an answer at all).

```
INSERT INTO tablename
("name", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5")
SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 15),  (random() * 4 + 1), (random() * 4 + 1), 
(random() * 4 + 1), (random() * 4 + 1), (random() * 4 + 1)
FROM generate_series(1, 10)
```

This query in its current state repeats the same lines

It isn't a problem to me if that exact number combination across the columns repeats in a future row, so DISTINCT isn't what I am looking for. Doesn't look like I can use EXISTS/NOT EXISTS either because the row doesn't exist yet.

Perhaps NOT EXISTS in a sub query might work? But I haven't figured out a way to do it with those yet.

Appreciate any help here, thanks.

Comment: These random numbers should be unique in columns (so e.g. if column1 takes a 5, column2 can no longer have value 5), or rows? e.g. if one row gets a 5 in column1 then no other row can get a 5 in column1?

Comment: The columns within the same row need to be unique, so your first guess is right. Rows with the same value in the same column in a different row can repeat, doesn't matter.

Comment: Right now you're generating doubles though, so the chance of collisions is quite literally very close to 0. Do you need these to be unique integers like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Comment: ? Not sure I get what you mean. As my current query stands, repeated numbers is very common, If col1 randomly generates as a 5, col2 still has a chance of being a 5 as well. Each column should use one of those 5 numbers and then subsequent columns must choose from the remaining 4 that weren't chosen. If col1 randomly generates as a 5, col2 should be 1, 2, 3 or 4. If col2 randomly generates as a 3, col3 should be a 1, 2 or 4 etc.

Comment: Your query currently generates doubles, have a look at the results of your SELECT [here on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=248e85d53b5a61c3ba67b6341b3dfad3). You're casting them to integers somehow though, that's fine. I'll post an answer in a sec.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to add the int casting in sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the following solution generates numbers from 1 to 5 using `generate_series` and then shuffles them into an array. Then the array is used to populate the table:

```
WITH generator AS (
   SELECT array_agg(gen.i ORDER BY random()) AS numbers
     FROM generate_series(1, 5) gen(i) -- range of numbers
    CROSS
     JOIN generate_series(1, 5) rows(i) -- number of rows
    GROUP BY rows.i
)
INSERT INTO tablename
(name, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
SELECT substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 15) AS name
     , gen.numbers[1]
     , gen.numbers[2]
     , gen.numbers[3]
     , gen.numbers[4]
     , gen.numbers[5]
  FROM generator gen
```

[Here's a working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9f3de9c50155eccaf914332a41bc26d8)

Comment: Thanks, works great.

Appreciate the quick response...looks like I'll need to look up some of these things you've used though, as I am not that familiar with generator.

Comment: generator is just a name I gave to the Common Table Expression (CTE, the `WITH` clause). You could name it foobar and it would still work the same.